# upwork-api client.auth.get_request_token() returns (null,null)

Tags: python, oauth, upwork-api

I am moving my first steps with the upwork API in python, but I am stuck at the first steps.
I am following the tutorials but I cannot get the tokens from oauth.

```
upwork.ca_certs_locater.LINUX_PATH = 'C:\\Users\\somedir\\cacert.pem'
client = upwork.Client(upwork_key, upwork_secret)
print("Please to this URL (authorize the app if necessary):")
print(client.auth.get_authorize_url())
print("After that you should be redirected back to your app URL with " +
"additional ?oauth_verifier= parameter")
```

the upwork library seems installed correctly, the .pem file is also loaded correctly and I think I can connect to the server.
The API keys are correctly enabled, checked with the support.
However client.auth.get_authorize_url()  returns empty parameters and auth.get_request_token() returns (null,null). 
What can be wrong? How do I enable logging to check where all gets stuck?

```
client.auth.get_authorize_url() returns:  
"https://www.upwork.com/services/api/auth?oauth_token=None"

client.auth.auth.get_request_token() returns:
(None, None)
```

I am using python 3.6

Comment: what version of python do you use? what exactly returns get_authorize_url?

Comment: added details in original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a "known" issue that may happen when Python3 is in use - README says: "These are Python (2, and 3 which is "supported" via unofficial PR #27 and not guaranteed) bindings for Upwork Public API".

Could you please try with Python 2.x

Comment: in the end I worked it around using requests-oauthlib, which works fine https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib
Once authentication is sorted out, the upwork API are not so complex to deserve a dedicated wrapper IMHO.

Comment: @Vitomakes: You might want to make this into an answer. Also, can you perhaps, show us the steps you used `requests-oauthlib`? ;)

Comment: there is pull request that support oauth python 3 compatibility. but not merged yet.
https://github.com/upwork/python-upwork/pull/39. Since, python 2.x was dead on january 2020, I think we should move code to be compatible with python 3

Comment: @ijogja, the Pull Request #39 was closed because Upwork works on a new library fully compatible with  Python 3. Please, stay tuned.